# Utilizing the screen space using css

Tags: css

I have a long list of items shown in this html format

```
<div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
   <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
        <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
   </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
</div>
```

What I am trying to acheive with CSS is that I show lets say maximum 10 and then float the rest to right and go on. I cannot change the html structure. All these items are inside a parent div.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Is this a html structure of a single item ?

Comment: yes this is one single item.

Comment: When it reach to 10 items you want to move right other next 10 and go on like this ?

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to acheive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a demo if its works for you..

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: table-cell;
}

.parent ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 13em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.epi-checkboxContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.epi-checkboxContainer:nth-child(n + 10) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC1</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="epi-checkboxContainer">
        <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitCheckBox dijitCheckBoxChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">
          <input type="checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_1" value="ZZC" style="user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <label for="dijit_form_CheckBox_1">ZZC</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```